# Scope not what I expect when using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scope

I want to input `df` into a function, call the output another dataframe 'df_fn', and have `df` be unchanged. How do I do that?

My code either does nothing and `df_fn` is equal to `df` or `df_fn` and `df` are both altered.

using `df_fn[cols][df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas'] = np.nan`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'n_wheels': [2, 4, 4],
                   'color': ['red', 'blue', 'red'],
                   'year': [2010, 1990, 1999],
                   'fuel_type': ['diesel', 'gas', 'electric']})
print('df = \n', df)
def fn(df_fn):

    cols = ['n_wheels', 'color', 'year']
#     df_fn.loc[df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas', cols] = np.nan
    df_fn[cols][df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas'] = np.nan


    return df_fn

new_df = fn(df)
print('df = \n', df)
print('new_df = \n', new_df)
```

output:

```
df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric

df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric

new_df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric
```

using `df_fn.loc[df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas', cols] = np.nan`

```
print('df = \n', df)
def fn(df_fn):

    cols = ['n_wheels', 'color', 'year']
#     df_fn[cols][df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas'] = np.nan
    df_fn.loc[df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas', cols] = np.nan


    return df_fn

new_df = fn(df)
print('df = \n', df)
print('new_df = \n', new_df)
```

output:

```
df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric
df = 
    n_wheels color    year fuel_type
0       NaN   NaN     NaN    diesel
1       4.0  blue  1990.0       gas
2       NaN   NaN     NaN  electric
new_df = 
    n_wheels color    year fuel_type
0       NaN   NaN     NaN    diesel
1       4.0  blue  1990.0       gas
2       NaN   NaN     NaN  electric
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need set a copy of original df

```
print('df = \n', df)
def fn(df_fn):
    cols = ['n_wheels', 'color', 'year']
#     df_fn[cols][df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas'] = np.nan
    df_fn.loc[df_fn.fuel_type != 'gas', cols] = np.nan
    return df_fn
df1=df.copy()#I change here add copy 
new_df = fn(df1)
print('df = \n', df)
print('new_df = \n', new_df)
df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric
df = 
    n_wheels color  year fuel_type
0         2   red  2010    diesel
1         4  blue  1990       gas
2         4   red  1999  electric
new_df = 
    n_wheels color    year fuel_type
0       NaN   NaN     NaN    diesel
1       4.0  blue  1990.0       gas
2       NaN   NaN     NaN  electric
```

Comment: Oh, yes that works. Can you please explain why my two versions didn't work? Shouldn't I not need to make a copy because of how scoping works?

Comment: @vivian first one will return a warning if you run it outside the function `df[cols][df.fuel_type != 'gas']=np.nan
` try , second one , will over write the original df without copy